# angular: material update to latest version. Not downloading the specified version

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2, angular-cli-v6, angular-material-6

I suppose to install specific version of `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` in the application. The same is provided in the package.json. But when do `npm i` it is downloading the latest package of material and cdk.

[image: Screenshot]

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Clone the [repo](https://github.com/jpremkumar/ng-6_1_4_material)
- Install package (`npm install`)
- verify downloaded package version (`ng -v`)

Comment: Remove the `^` character from the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your package.json to use exact version as below :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.4.1",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "6.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
```

As per [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-exact) You can also set your **npm** config to use exact version rather than using npm's default semver range operator by running below :

```
npm config set save-exact true
```